# How do I open a new PHP page with posted data from a javascript file

Tags: javascript, php

I have updated my form:

```
<form method = "post" name= "account" action= "validated.php" target="_blank">
...
<submit value= "submit" onclick= "validate()" >Submit</submit>
```

It validates correctly from the validate.js file but still does not open a new page for validated.php

In validated.php just to start:

```
<p>Welcome <?php echo $_GET["fname"]; ?><br>
Your email address is: <?php echo $_GET["email"]; ?> and your birthday is: <?php echo $_GET["bdate"]; ?>
</p>
```

I think the issue is in the html. Any ideas?

Comment: what is the function `validate()`? What is in the file `validate.js`? It seems a very odd way to do things though

Comment: That form causes a POST request for "validate.js", which means the POST params get discarded. You're also stringifying strings, which makes no sense, and `xhttp.send()` doesn't accept multiple arguments like that. There's also no reason to use JSON in the first place if that's three input fields filled out by the user. There's further no reason to use ajax/xhttp if you're going to open a new window. Just keep things simple and use standard POST form submission for now.

Comment: <form method="post"> add this method attribute and check

Comment: There is no `submit` tag in HTML

Comment: Thanks heaps for the quick response. Ill do some adjustments and try again.

Comment: Here's a minimal example with validation for the first field: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/8wpL9qny/ In `validate.php`, simply check `$_POST['fname']` etc. Note that submitting a form via ajax is *NOT* what you do when you want to submit a form from code; it's what you do when you want to submit data *in the background*, without switching to a new page. Form validation and submission in JS means handling the submit event and preventing it, if validation fails.

Comment: few points: don't stringfy each, actually no need to stringyfy anything, just get the form object and load it inside `FormData`, then you send it

Comment: You changed your question. I had to change my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code makes no sense at all.

I am answering the question that had XMLHttpRequest in it

1. There exists no tag called submit
2. You have $_GET but you POST your xmlhttprequest

Since you want to open a new page in PHP, just have this (default is GET)

```
<form name="account" action= "validated.php">
  ...
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

BUT if you really want to ajax, you need to change your $_GET to $_POST and do something like this

```js
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
  document.getElementById("account").addEventListener("submit",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("fname", this.fname.value);
    formData.append("email", this.email.value); // assuming field names here
    formData.append("bdate",this.bdate.value);
    console.log(formData);
    const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onload=function(response) { console.log(response) }; // or some other process
    xhttp.open("POST", 'validated.php', true);
    xhttp.send(formData);
  });
});
```

using a form with an ID

```html
<form id="account">
...
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: I'm 99% sure OP thinks submitting a form in JS = Ajax (common beginner's mistake); I don't think they actually want to use Ajax, given their question title alone

Comment: Thank you all for your valuable feedback. There were a few rookie errors in there that didnt help and I was certainly going the wrong way about it. Note to self: an input with type ="submit" is not the same as <submit></submit>